# Only a type can be imported. package.ClassName resolves to a package

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I have written a dynamic web project in Eclipse Neon.3. So when I test it from localhost on my PC everything is working perfectly but when I export it to projectName.war and deploy it on my hosting server I'm getting:

> ```
> HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error"
> ```

and

> ```
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
> ```

for all of my imported classes in all `jsp` files.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"
    import="classes.User, classes.LogWriter, classes.Students, classes.Information" %>
```

That is from `index.jsp`. Here also gives an error from `head.Login.checkLogin()` which is:

> ```
> head.Login cannot be resolved to a type.
> ```

Comment: Did you forget a `.*` at the end of your `import` statement?

Comment: Also, please try to make a habit of sharing your problematic code in your question.  Makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling Tomcat and Java has done the job.